# Sum of Each Object Values

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am trying to sum of all values of each map object in looping. I was tried upto below code but it doesn't work. I have list of map object (`hrPersonnels`) and  One map object will contain many key's and values, I wanted to get sum of the each map object

```
<td>Total</td>
<td th:each="hrp:${hrPersonnels}" class="text-right">
<span th:text="${ #aggregates.sum(hrp)}"> 
</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just Iterate through the List and through the Hashmaps and at the end you just sum the values and add it to a new List. In thymeleaf you can just iterate through the new List. It will look like that:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> hrPersonnels = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();

ArrayList<Integer> aListOfSum = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < hrPersonnels.size(); i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(Integer d: hrPersonnels.get(i).values()) {
        sum += d;
    }
    aListOfSum.add(sum);
}
```

As I said in thymeleaf just iterate through the `aListOfSum`.

In thymeleaf it would look like that:

```
td>Total</td>
<tr th:each="sum: ${aListOfSum}">
    <span th:text="${sum}"></span>
</tr>
```

Comment: I also forget to mention that you have to add the list to your Model to access it from thymeleaf.